# Where to find FM satellite information

Tags: satellites

I'm new to satellites and I am trying to find all the information for everything.

Where can I find a list of all the operational FM amateur satellites with the down-link and up-link frequencies?

Also, where can I find the list of the ones that are only Beacon Downlink, and other like SSB?

Answer (score 1):

Most of the satellites featuring Amateur Radio transmissions and access are listed at [amsat.org](http://amsat.org).

You can also find [a list of operating Amateur Radio satellites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSCAR) on Wikipedia, and searching their names will bring up sites that show their capability.  There is also a list of Amateur Radio satellites, including cubesats, and on the [SatBlog](http://www.dk3wn.info/satellites.shtml) which may prove useful. These two sites are useful primarily because Amsat has occasional database issues.

Comment: In addition to the list of satellites, such as amsat.org, you can use satellite tracking software like gpredict: http://gpredict.oz9aec.net/. It downloads the satellite information and calculates which are above the horizon at the moment.